# Is it possible for a customer to have a DeviceID but no System/ Device Token generated in SFMC MobilePush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We have the MobilePush SDK integrated in the app by our developers. This just came up as a question during one of our discussions with the stakeholders. As per my understanding the Device ID gets generated for anyone that have installed the app but System/ Device token will only be generated once the user grants the permissions to receive Push. So in case a user does not opt in for Push, will they have a device ID and no System Token?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the push is not opted in, we will still have deviceID but not the system token. System token are received from APNS when the application registers for push notifications. The application should set to the mobilepush sdk to get registered to the mobile push servers.

Thanks
Prakashini

Comment: Thank you so much! This is helpful.
Follow up question - What if a customer opted into push at the beginning and then later opted out. Would we have the token for such customers?